# Akka streams Source.actorRef vs Source.queue vs buffer, which one to use?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am using akka-streams-kafka to created a stream consumer from a kafka topic. 
Using broadcast to serve events from kafka topic to web socket clients.

I have found following three approaches to create a stream Source. 
Question:
 My goal is to serve hundreds/thousands of websocket clients (some of which might be slow consumers). Which approach scales better?

Appreciate any thoughts?
Broadcast lowers the rate down to slowest consumer.
BUFFER_SIZE = 100000

1. Source.ActorRef (source actor does not support backpressure option)

   ```
   val kafkaSourceActorWithBroadcast = {

     val (sourceActorRef, kafkaSource) = Source.actorRef[String](BUFFER_SIZE, OverflowStrategy.fail)
                                         .toMat(BroadcastHub.sink(bufferSize = 256))(Keep.both).run

     Consumer.plainSource(consumerSettings, 
                Subscriptions.topics(KAFKA_TOPIC))
        .runForeach(record => sourceActorRef ! Util.toJson(record.value()))

   kafkaSource
   }
   ```
2. Source.queue

   ```
   val kafkaSourceQueueWithBroadcast = {

     val (futureQueue, kafkaQueueSource) = Source.queue[String](BUFFER_SIZE, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
                                           .toMat(BroadcastHub.sink(bufferSize = 256))(Keep.both).run

   Consumer.plainSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(KAFKA_TOPIC))
           .runForeach(record => futureQueue.offer(Util.toJson(record.value())))

   kafkaQueueSource
   }
   ```
3. buffer

   ```
   val kafkaSourceWithBuffer = Consumer.plainSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics(KAFKA_TOPIC))
                                 .map(record => Util.toJson(record.value()))
                                 .buffer(BUFFER_SIZE, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
                                 .toMat(BroadcastHub.sink(bufferSize = 256))(Keep.right).run
   ```

Websocket route code for completeness:

```
val streamRoute =
    path("stream") {
      handleWebSocketMessages(websocketFlow)
    }


def websocketFlow(where: String): Flow[Message, Message, NotUsed] = {

  Flow[Message]
   .collect {
    case TextMessage.Strict(msg) => Future.successful(msg)
    case TextMessage.Streamed(stream) =>
      stream.runFold("")(_ + _).flatMap(msg => Future.successful(msg))
  }
  .mapAsync(parallelism = PARALLELISM)(identity)
  .via(logicStreamFlow)
  .map { msg: String => TextMessage.Strict(msg) }
}


private def logicStreamFlow: Flow[String, String, NotUsed] = 
         Flow.fromSinkAndSource(Sink.ignore, kafkaSourceActorWithBroadcast)
```